# How to get a both side colored plane in A-Frame

Tags: aframe, webvr

When I create an `a-plane` and assign an attribute `color="red"`, the color is applied to one side only. I added rotation animation to the plane and the back of the plane is white: [fiddle](https://codepen.io/Yeniv/pen/NMOWmx?editors=1100).

What would be the method to get a plane colored from both sides? Should I create 2 planes of same color and then rotate one so that they are back to back and to the user looks like a single plane?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `material` property called side. If you set it to `double`, the material will be applied both to `front` and `back`

```
<a-entity material="side: double"></a-entity>
```

snippet:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" width="4" height="4" 
           color="#7BC8A4" material="side: double"
           animation="property: rotation; to: 360 0 0; loop: true; dur: 2500">
  </a-plane>
</a-scene>
```